# How to hide this view on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

On recent versions of android studio there's this view that I just can't hide. It's helpful in some contexts, like when you're creating views, but It keeps on showing when I'm writing java code. How do I hide it? I can hide everything else but this view and its really annoying.

[image: view]